# ng-show fade animation happening on redirect

Tags: javascript, angularjs, animation

So, I have this pop-up that should be hidden by default by an ng-show, until a button is pressed. My problem is that when navigating to these pages without a hard refresh, the pop up is initially shown and then fades out.

What I think is happening is that for some reason the ng-show initially evaluates to true, or maybe the angular hasn't actually been compiled yet, so the pop-up would normally be shown and immediately hidden, but because of the 0.5s transition, it has to fade out instead.

Anyone have any ideas why this is happening, or ways around it?

HTML:

```
<div class="test-fade" ng-show="completeAll">
  <p>You are about to complete some stuff</p>
  <button ng-click="doStuff()">Complete</button>
  <button ng-click="completeAll = false">Cancel</button>
</div>

<button ng-click="completeAll = true">
   <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
</button>
```

CSS:

```
.test-fade{
  -webkit-transition:all linear 0.5s;
  transition:all linear 0.5s;
}
  .test-fade.ng-hide{
  opacity:0;
}
```

JS Controller:

```
$scope.completeAll = false
```

Because I set the completeAll variable to false initially in my controller, I have a sinking feeling this problem stems from angular's compiling order or some other equally scary angular intricacy. Hope you guys can help!

Comment: can you provide a fiddle ? Also, if it is your problem of angular not being compiled, you could have initially your div hidden.

Comment: Hey Gonzalo, after an hour I can't seem to get ngAnimate working in a fiddle. Here's what I'm left with: https://jsfiddle.net/Lbn58ybz/8/

But ignoring that failed fiddle, how do you suggest hiding the div? I've tried setting the div's default visibility to hidden, then setting and ng-class to remove it once the controller has loaded, but this didn't solve the problem.

Comment: You may want to check this https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak

Comment: Thanks for the link! I didn't know about ngCloak. Unfortunately it also didn't solve the problem. I ended up just setting visibility back to hidden by default on the original div, then adding an `ng-class="{unhidden:completeAll}"` where unhidden is: `&.unhidden{ visibility:visible }`. So the visibility is also dependent on the `completeAll` variable. This is a work-around to the actual problem, but it did the trick. Thanks for the help!